# How can i get the module path in logback.xml

Tags: java, xml

How can i get the module path in my logback.xml, for example like the process id, which is :

```
{
"process": "${PID}",
}
```

I tried this `${LOG_PATH}` but is not working, actually...

Comment: You can insert any system property, so as the duplicate answer shows, you can use `${jdk.module.path}`

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this.
You'll have to add to your app.yml or app.properties this:

```
logging:
  file:
    path: "your-module-name"
```

then you must include this in your logback.xml:

```
"source": "${LOG_PATH}"
```